# Openweathermap API Forecast accessing array

Tags: arrays, android-studio, openweathermap

So I'm trying to mess around with the openweathermap API and I can't figure out how to access some of the data.

Here the snippet of code I have that access the API.

```
    public void find_forecast () {

    String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=4466033&appid=e4c641dd837c7947a127972091185dad&units=imperial";

    JsonObjectRequest jor = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("list");
                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(1);

                String description = object.getString("dt");
                day1.setText(description);
```

Here is a snippet of the API code:

```
{
"cod": "200",
"message": 0.0042,
"cnt": 40,
"list": [
    {
        "dt": 1524614400,
        "main": {
            "temp": 63.77,
            "temp_min": 63.77,
            "temp_max": 64.26,
            "pressure": 1017.45,
            "sea_level": 1021.4,
            "grnd_level": 1017.45,
            "humidity": 97,
            "temp_kf": -0.27
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 500,
                "main": "Rain",
                "description": "light rain",
                "icon": "10n"
            }
        ],
```

So as you can see the code above will return the value of dt which is 1524614400. But I'm trying to access for example under "weather" the "description" which in this case is light rain. I guess I don't know how to access an array inside an array, although I couldn't even get the "temp" to return under "main", although I could get "main" to return everything underneath it.

Thanks for any help.

Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out. Code is below!

```
String array = response.getJSONArray("list").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0).getString("description");
                day1.setText(array);
```

This will return light rain from the API code above.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Android but in Javascript I would try this:

```
var dataObj = {
"cod": "200",
"message": 0.0042,
"cnt": 40,
"list": [
    {
        "dt": 1524614400,
        "main": {
            "temp": 63.77,
            "temp_min": 63.77,
            "temp_max": 64.26,
            "pressure": 1017.45,
            "sea_level": 1021.4,
            "grnd_level": 1017.45,
            "humidity": 97,
            "temp_kf": -0.27
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 500,
                "main": "Rain",
                "description": "light rain",
                "icon": "10n"
            }
        ]
      }
      ]
  }

  console.log(dataObj.list[0].weather[0].description);
```